# Odds of winning a Raffle with multiple winners

Tags: probability

I am creating a raffle with 8191 entries and will select 63 winners. I would like to calculate the odds of each player winning.

I've seen some questions here and now understand that, if I had only one selected winner and the player bought only one ticket he/she would have 1 in 8191 chances of winning, and if the player bought 2 tickets, would be 2 in 8191... That is correct, right?

But since I have 63 winners, how do I calculate the odds for this? And what if players bought more than one ticket? Because the payout is the same for all players, I've assumed I could divide the whole raffle by the number of winners, so I did 8191/63 = 130 is it right to say that the odds are 1 in 130 for this raffle and if the player bought 2 tickets, the player would have 2 in 130?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: To be clear, for a player who buys two tickets... are you asking for the probability of winning *at least once* or are you asking for the *expected number of wins*?  These are different concepts with similar but slightly different answers and different ways of calculating them.

Answer (score 1):

The odds of each *ticket* winning is 63/8191.  If each winner was for a different prize, then each ticket would have 1/8191 chance of winning a particular prize, but because there are 63 different prizes, the odds that a ticket wins *some* prize goes up.

If you want to know the odds that a person wins, things are more complicated.  A single ticket cannot win more than one prize, but if a person purchases multiple tickets, they can.  The expected number of prizes they win is straight forward: the number of tickets they bought times the probability that one prize wins a ticket.  But this is divided amongst cases where they win no prizes, or one, or two, or three, etc., each with their own individual probabilities.

We can work out the probabilities in general, but for simplicity, let's just find the probability that someone wins no prizes.  Let's say they bought $k$ tickets.  There are $\binom{8191}{k}$ choices for which set of $k$ tickets they could have bought, each equally likely.  How many of those sets only contain losing tickets?  There are 8191-63 losing tickets, and so there are $\binom{8101-63}{k}$ sets of tickets that are all losing tickets.  Therefore, the probability that every ticket is a loser is the ratio of the number of losing sets to the total number of sets, or $\frac{\binom{8101-63}{k}}{\binom{8191}{k}}$.  The probability that the person wins *at least one* prize is then $1-\frac{\binom{8101-63}{k}}{\binom{8191}{k}}$.